# TFS SDK - Associate work item with checkin by id

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild, tfs-sdk

I am using TFS SDK (Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient).
I have a list of work items IDs (workItemsToAssociate) and I am doing a check-in, associating these workitems:

```
var workItemStore = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
var associatedWorkItems = workItemsToAssociate?.Select(workItemId => new WorkItemCheckinInfo(workItemStore.GetWorkItem(workItemId), WorkItemCheckinAction.Associate)).ToArray();
var wip = new WorkspaceCheckInParameters(changes, comment) {
    AssociatedWorkItems = associatedWorkItems
}
workspace.CheckIn(wip);
```

But I faced a problem with native dll Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll (part of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client), since it isn't getting into my bin folder (the only common solution I have found is to put it manually).

The code above is located in the LRT.SourceRepositoryProviders project, which is referenced by LRT.Console project, where the app starts. After build this native dll Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll appears in LRT.SourceRepositoryProviders bin folder, but i have to manually put it into LRT.Console bin folder.

1) Is there a way to achieve what do i want without using WorkItemStore? WorkItemCheckinInfo requires a WorkItem object, but I wish I could just pass ID list to checkin.

2) How can I configure solution so that native lib Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll will be placed in all bin folders correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use WorkItemStore to get the work item information.

There is a another sample for your reference about [How to checkin source code with work item associated using TFS API.](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-Checkin-Source-Code-65b278be)

**Microsoft.WITDataStore*.dll** is part of the ExtendedClient package, they are native dlls and cannot be referenced in managed project. You will need to manually copy the dll into your bin folder for runtime resolution.

You can try to add the dll to the startup-project (LRT.SourceRepositoryProviders project) of the solution.